# What exactly is a monkey doing messing with my Android phone?

Tags: android, testing, monkeyrunner

Looking through the Android apis I found a method call [isUserAMonkey()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isUserAMonkey%28%29),
says it returns `true` if the phone is being messed with by a monkey.

Is this a joke, or what is it used for?

Comment: My customer tests the app for crashes like a professional musican. He drums on the phone/tablet with 10 fingers... thats like a monkey...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html), it will give you the answer.

Quote from the document:

> The monkeyrunner tool provides an API for writing programs that
>   control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code.
>   With monkeyrunner, you can write a Python program that installs an
>   Android application or test package, runs it, sends keystrokes to it,
>   takes screenshots of its user interface, and stores screenshots on the
>   workstation. The monkeyrunner tool is primarily designed to test
>   applications and devices at the functional/framework level and for
>   running unit test suites, but you are free to use it for other
>   purposes.

So if you are running a package using Monkeyrunner, then this function will return true.

Comment: To elaborate, since the monkey testing tool can potentially cause a lot of mischief, if you use it to test your app it is good practice to make sure that you protect operations within your app with a call to `isUserAMonkey` and ignore the operation if it returns true. Otherwise you might have monkeys sending email, posting random gibberish to the internet, triggering operations that cost money, etc.

Comment: @adamp - i don't like those monkeys

Comment: I believe MonkeyRunner mentioning is wrong here. isUserMonkey() checks whether monkey tool is running (not a monkeyrunner). MonkeyRunner is a framework to write UI automation tests. Monkey tool is a tool to generate random events.